# How to print text after third same line?

Tags: awk

I have an input - there are three times same line something and same line.

```
o 0  1 0 1 1      5.732820000     0.000 = PERIOD(0)
5456
text4
o 2 11 0 1 1      0.000000000     0.100 = d q/dt
o 0  1 0 1 1      5.732820000     0.000 = PERIOD(0)
454
785 text7
o 2 11 0 1 1      0.000000000     0.100 = d q/dt
o 0  1 0 1 1      5.732820000     0.000 = PERIOD(0)
4
text78
o 2 11 0 1 1      0.000000000     0.100 = d q/dt
```

I would like to print text between third "same line" and third "end same line". How to do that please?

The desired output:

```
4
text78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^end same line$/{f=0}c==3&&f==1;/^same line$/{c++;f=1}' file
4
text78
```

Explanation

- Count occurences of `^same line$` in `c`
- Set `f=1` when between `^same line$` and `^end same line$`
- Print line if `c==3` and `f==1`

The expression order controls whether start or end markers (`same line`) are included in the output.

Comment: Thank you very much and what does this mistake mean please? I replaced the text of start and end
`awk: cmd. line:1: /^o 2 11 0 1 1      0.000000000     0.100 = d q/dt$/{f=0}c==3&&f==1;/^o 0  1 0 1 1      5.732820000     0.000 = PERIOD(0)$/{c++;f=1}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                               ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: /^o 2 11 0 1 1      0.000000000     0.100 = d q/dt$/{f=0}c==3&&f==1;/^o 0  1 0 1 1      5.732820000     0.000 = PERIOD(0)$/{c++;f=1}
awk: cmd. line:1: `

Comment: @MarciaCross Your search string contains a `/`. You need to escape it as it's the regex pattern delimiter. Also, if you'd have more special characters in your search string, you need to escape them as well. So the string between `^` and `$` should read `o 2 11 0 1 1 0.000000000 0.100 = d q\/dt`.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why it does not work for input I add to my question. There is no error, but an output file is empty.

Comment: @MarciaCross For two reasons: (1) You have more than one space (or a tabular) before and after `0.000000000`, so you should replace the single space with `\s+` and (2) you don't have 3 or 4 paragraphs inside the pattern, only two. Plus, you didn't ask the correct question, because your end pattern is equal to the start pattern (which is different to your original question).

Comment: Thank you, so I should write `\s+` instead of single space and where is more space let more space? I am sorry word end was not appropriate. It should have been a normal string.

Comment: @MarciaCross `\s+` stands for white space (at least one). If start and end search strings are the same, it's easier, as you would only count the matches and print while match count equals 3 (or 2 in your example).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197886/discussion-between-marcia-cross-and-steffen).

Answer (score 1):

For your specific file data format:

```
awk '/^same line/ && ++cnt == 3{ found=1; next }found && /^end same line/{ exit }found' file
```

- `found && /^end same line/{ exit }` - will exit on particular section preventing redundant processing (according to *"between third "same line" and third "end same line""*)

The output:

```
4
text78
```